# clip-path is not animating?

Tags: css, css-animations, clip-path

**WHAT I HAVE**
I have a div (class = circle), I set key-fames for 4s so that it nicely animates from triangle to octagon.

```css
body {
    background-color: #252525;
    height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 5rem;

    background-color: #1c7ed6;

    animation: wave--animate 4s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}

@keyframes wave--animate {

    0% {
        /* triangle */
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);

    }

    100% {
        /* octagon */
        clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);

    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="section--water-waves">
        <p class=circle></p>
    </section>
</body>
```

**WHAT I NEED**
but, it immediately changes to octagon, instead of nicely and slowly getting animated to octagon...

Comment: you need to have the same number of points inside the polygon

Comment: so, can you help me in keeping same points?